# how to get row number via condition of Matrix

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

how can i get the row number of matrix, the condition is last 5 number of column1 and column2.value > 10 ?

i want to use this to high light top 5 rows and last 5 rows and column2.value >10.

top 5 need to highlight one kind of color, the last 5 rows needs to highlight another color.

i had solve the top 5, but i tried below

```
count(iif(sum(Fields!M_QTY.Value)>Fields!OVER_FLOW_CHECK_POINT_FILTER.Value,1,0))
```

but it cannot apply for group field

//------------20140404
i think i am not describe very clear

my matrix format like below link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEek2.jpg

i want to put the condition on the product name, and for the detail cells, it's including

```
sum()
```

but `iif` looks like cannot using `sum(values)` as conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to follow your description of the requirements, but I think you should change your count function for something like this:

`= RunningValue ( iif ( ... ) , Count )`

To get the last 5 I would try to compare it with a CountDistinct of the Row Group fields, e.g.

`= Iif ( RunningValue ( iif ( ... ) , Count ) >= CountDistinct ( Fields!GroupField.Value , "tablix1" ) , "#Red" , "#White" )`

Comment: i think i am not describe very clear

my matrix format like below link http://i.stack.imgur.com/OEek2.jpg

i want to put the condition on the product name, and for the detail cells, it's including
`sum()`
but `iif` looks like cannot using `sum(values)` as conditions.

Comment: I still have little idea of what you are trying to achieve or what your issue is.  Exactly what do you mean by "iif looks like cannot using"?  Even trying to ignore your multiple grammatical mistakes, that means nothing technically.